# Extending a Flutter widget with a GestureDetector

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to update my `Drawer` to a `NavigationDrawer` that uses `NavigationDrawerDestination` widgets. However, I'm very unhappy with the fact that `NavigationDrawerDestinaion`'s do not have a callback function. The `onDestinationSelected` function only takes the index of the destination, and nothing else, for handling taps. In my Drawer this is cumbersome as for some users the amount and order of destinations varies.

I cannot wrap the `NavigationDrawerDestination` in a `GestureDetector` directly as Flutter expects the parent of a `NavigationDrawerDestination` to be a `NavigationDrawer`. Thus, I tried to extend the widget by creating a `SidebarDestination` like so:

```dart
class SidebarDestination extends NavigationDrawerDestination {
  const SidebarDestination({
    super.key,
    required super.icon,
    required super.label,
    super.selectedIcon,
    required this.onTap,
  });

  final void Function() onTap;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: super.build(context),
    );
  }
}
```

A complete code example is available in [this DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=5f3ccaf0f60b2114fc06f6088b6ec98a). This no longer raises errors from the framework. However, the GestureDetector in my extension widget does not fire: tapping the destination does not print "This is not printed!" in the console.

How do I correctly implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other cases like this tap event win for the inner event.

You can use `onPanDown` on this case to overcome this situation.

```dart
 return GestureDetector(
    onPanDown:(_)=> onTap(),
```